# How to Generate Sequence Number with MongoDB in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql

I am working on a Spring Boot project and decided to use MongoDB . I just want to generate sequence number in MongoDB. So even if 100s of different clients trying to do that, I do not want to conflict any generated number. Is there any way to do that ?

Also I tried to make something like this :

```
SequenceNumber sequenceNumber;

        String SEQUENCE_NAME = "example";

        sequenceNumber = mongoOperations.findAndModify(query(where("_id").is(SEQUENCE_NAME)),
                new Update().inc("number", 1), options().returnNew(true).upsert(true),
                SequenceNumber.class);
                
 return sequenceNumber.getNumber();
```

Is this correct ?

Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0):

https://www.javaprogramto.com/2019/05/spring-boot-mongodb-auto-generated-field.html

1. First, create a collection that will store the auto-incremented value in it. This can be created using either the mongo shell or MongoDB Compass

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "database_sequences")
public class DatabaseSequence {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private long seq;

    public DatabaseSequence() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getSeq() {
        return seq;
    }

    public void setSeq(long seq) {
        this.seq = seq;
    }
}
```

2. Let’s then create a users_db collection. This collection stores the users that are being used.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "users_db")
public class User {

    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "users_sequence";

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    public User() { }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' + ", email='" + email + '\'' + '}';
    }
```

Comment: I want to make sequence  for each invoking function. For Ex,  I call generateSequence() from A Service , but  simultaneously another services can call function and There will be a performance problem. How can I perform this ?